# Verification of a proof that the difference of two odd integers is not odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

> Prove or disprove the difference of two odd integers is odd.

Here was my answer:

$m = 2s+1$

$n = 2t+1$

$m - n = (2s+1) - (2t+1)$

$= 2s - 2t$

$= 2(s-t)$

I then wrote the following:

> Since $2(s-t)$ is even this is disproved since $(s-t)$ is an integer.

I didn't even get half a point, so is this answer completely wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your wording is a little bit awkward. I don't see why you didn't get any credit.

Comment: The instructor may have not given you credit because you didn't specify initially what $s$ and $t$ are. You never stated that they were integers. Some instructors are nitpick about that.

Comment: I hope you asked your teacher before enquiring here.  Firstly, it's just polite.  Secondly you will have some chance of learning what was in your teacher's mind, which nobody here can possibly give you.

Comment: As a side not, in this context a counterexample would have been sufficient to disprove the given statement. For example, you could have noted that 3 is an odd integer, yet 3-3=0 is even.

Comment: You have a good sketch of the idea, but perhaps your professor expected a more polished answer.

Comment: @Jonny I would be able to understand and except that if I were attending a face-to-face class, but this is an online class and the teacher literally assigns reading material and then an assignment.  There is no "teaching." So it's very frustrating trying to guess what the teacher is looking for.

Comment: My answer was based upon how the textbook demonstrated doing these types of questions.

Comment: The statement in the title and the body are actually different questions. For the body question, a single counterexample is all that's needed to disprove it. But to prove that the difference of two odd numbers is not odd requires you to prove it for all values...

Comment: "so is this answer completely wrong?" What is $m$? What is $n$? What is $s$? What is $t$? What is the definition of odd? How do you know that an even number is not odd?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I think it's obvious what the variables are.  And in the context of the question why should I define odd if I'm taking the difference of two odd numbers which is easily seen in my answer?  Lastly, and I mean this with the utmost respect, I have no idea what you're talking about?  How don't know an even number is not odd?  Because it's even.  I think..?  Can you explain this to me?

Comment: No, it is not obvious what the variables are. Always be explicit. If you are going to prove something about a notion, you should at least acknowledge its definition. Many times the difficulties lie simply in not realizing what the precise meaning is of the terms involved in the question. Now, is the definition of odd "A number that is not even"? Or is it something else? Your sketch seems to indicate that this is not the definition. So your idea is at best incomplete. Yes, you may think it is obvious that even numbers are not odd. That's not enough. Add a proof. It is not entirely trivial.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I respect your comments although i disagree with you thinking my answer is incorrect.  My answer is not perfect but it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have said:

Let $m=2k_1+1,\ k_1\in\mathbb Z$ and $n=2k_2+1,\ k_2\in\mathbb Z$.  We have $m-n=2k_1+1-(2k_2+1)=2k_1-2k_2=2(k_1-k_2).$ Let $k=k_1-k_2.$ Then we have $m-n=2k,\ k\in\mathbb Z$ which implies that $m-n$ is even.  Therefore, the difference of two odd integers is even.

Comment: Um, do you mean $m=2k_1+1$?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: This is not a complete argument at this level. Assuming that the definition of odd is a number $a$ for which there is an integer $b$ such that $a=2b+1$, you proved that the difference of two odd numbers is even. This is not the same as proving that the difference is not odd.